# Using qsort on a struct that contains strings

Tags: c, arrays, struct, qsort

I want to use qsort() function in my program.

I want to sort this struct by strings.

I just made pointers.

I searched the internet but I didn't get it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b)

{
    const char* aa = *(const char**)a;
    const char* bb = *(const char**)b;
    return strcmp(aa,bb);
}

typedef struct
{   int x;
    char a[10];

}alex;
int main()
{
    alex vd[10];
int i;
//vd=malloc(sizeof(struct alex)*2);
strcpy(vd[0].a,"dinamitte");
strcpy(vd[1].a,"alex");
printf("Before : \n");
for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    printf("%s ",vd[i].a);

//qsort(v,1,sizeof (v) ,myCompare);
int n=2;
//qsort(v, 2, sizeof (char *), cstring_cmp);
qsort(vd,n  ,sizeof(alex),cmpstr);
//qsort()
printf("\nAfter : \n");
for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    printf("%s \n",vd[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

After I compile, it writes on screen 'dinamitte' and 'alex' and then some weird characters.

Comment: Your `cmpstr` function is wrong. because top of member of `alex` has `int`.

Comment: but shouldnt i return a value ?

Comment: Also `printf("%s \n",vd[i]);` typo as `printf("%s \n",vd[i].a);`

Comment: man you are awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    char a[10];
} alex;

int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b){
    const alex *aa = a;
    const alex *bb = b;
    return strcmp(aa->a, bb->a);
}
```

Also `printf("%s \n",vd[i]);` typo as `printf("%s \n",vd[i].a);`

Comment: and if if want to replace that "typedef" ? how it should look like ?

Comment: @AlexandruBucurie It must be defined before using with `cmpstr`.

Comment: and what if i have

Comment: struct oras
{
    int id ;
    struct loc adresa ;
    struct comandaa comanda ;
    union bani_ramasi bani ;
    struct persona client ;
} ;

Comment: struct persona
{
    int VIP ;
    char nume[ 30 ] ;
} ;

Comment: i want to sort by "nume"

Comment: Please do it. What is the problem?

Comment: You do the same this.

Comment: int cmpstr(const void *a, const void *b){
    const struct oras *aa = a;
    const struct oras *bb = b;
    return strcmp(aa->client->nume, bb->client->nume);
}
void scrie_v(struct oras v[],int n)
{int i;
    qsort(v, n, sizeof(v), cmpstr);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",v[i].client.nume);
}

Comment: `sizeof(v)` is wrong. This should be one record size. E.g. `sizeof(struct oras)` or `sizeof(*v)`. Also `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` --> `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` and `aa->client->nume` --> `aa->client.nume` right?

Comment: int cmpstr(const void *a, const void *b){
    const struct oras *aa = a;
    const struct oras *bb = b;
    return strcmp(aa->client.nume,bb->client.nume);
}
void scrie_v(struct oras v[],int n)
{int i;
    qsort(v, n, sizeof(struct oras), cmpstr);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",v[i].client.nume);
}